# R - unlist into dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a list of vectors in R:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 7 9 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 8 2 1

[[4]]
[1] 8 9 0 7
```

And I want to make a `dataframe` out of them. The problem is, I can't simply use unlist and then reorganize, because not all the vectors are the same length – I want NAs in my dataframe when that happens. The final result should look like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
1     2     3     4
7     9     1     4
8     2     1     NA
8     9     0     7
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting nested list (unequal length) to data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153979/converting-nested-list-unequal-length-to-data-frame)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R list of data frames to data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141889/r-list-of-data-frames-to-data-frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `purrr` you can do the following:

```
require(purrr)
L <- list(1:4, c(7,9,1,4), c(8,2,1), c(8,9,0,7))
map_df(L, ~as.data.frame(t(.)))
```

Which gives you:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  7  9  1  4
3  8  2  1 NA
4  8  9  0  7
```

**Base R approach:**

```
clen <- vapply(L, length, integer(1))
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(L), ncol = max(clen))
for(i in seq_along(L)){
  mat[i, seq(1, clen[i])] <- L[[i]]
}
as.data.frame(mat)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in base R (where `ls` is your list object):

```
data.frame(t(sapply(ls, function(x) x[1:max(lengths(ls))])))
```

Which given your data will give you:

```
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1  2  3  4
#2  7  9  1  4
#3  8  2  1 NA
#4  8  9  0  7
```

In general, `c(1:5)[1:7]` will give you

```
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

cbind.ts will work on objects of different lengths.  Using that we can get the following one line base solution:

```
as.data.frame(t(unname(do.call("cbind", lapply(L, ts)))))
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  7  9  1  4
3  8  2  1 NA
4  8  9  0  7
```

This could alternately be expressed as a magrittr pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)

L %>% 
  lapply(ts) %>% 
  do.call(what = "cbind") %>% 
  t %>% 
  unname %>% 
  as.data.frame
```

**Note:** We used this as the input:

```
L <- list(1:4, c(7, 9, 1, 4), c(8, 2, 1), c(8, 9, 0, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use the `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi` and convert to `mode` from `character` to `integer`

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- stri_list2matrix(L, byrow=TRUE)
mode(m1) <- "integer"
m1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    7    9    1    4
#[3,]    8    2    1   NA
#[4,]    8    9    0    7
```

`matrix` can be converted to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame` so

```
as.data.frame(m1)
```

#### data

```
L <- list(1:4, c(7, 9, 1, 4), c(8, 2, 1), c(8, 9, 0, 7))
```